# split object as coproduct

Tags: category-theory

Let $X$ be an object and $f : Y \to X$ a monomorphism in some category with coproducts. Is there a categorical characterization for objects $Z$ such that $Y + Z \cong X$ and left injection composed with the isomorphism is equal to $f$?

Comment: I suppose you want something other than "there is $g: Z\to X$ such that for all morphisms $h_1:Y\to A$, $h_2:Z\to A$, there is a unique morphism $h:X\to A$ such that $h_1=h\circ f$ and $h_2=h\circ g$" ?

Comment: Yes. For example, I could "characterize" the preimage of $f$ by using the pullback over $f$ and the identity. In set theoretic terms, I'd like something like the complement of this.

Comment: In general $Z$ neither exists nor is unique (consider the case of abelian groups to see this). I don't know anything nice to say here unless the ambient category is something like abelian.